# No method of un-setting cookies is working

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to unset/delete/expire cookies on a logout page. However, it doesn't seem to be working. My logout script reads as follows:

```
require_once("database.php"); // contains session_start()
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

// attempts to unset cookies go here (see below)

var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
header("Location: ./login.php");
exit();
```

My three attempts to remove a specific cookie `login` (or all of them), are as follows:

**Attempt 1:**

```
setcookie("login", "", time() -3600, "/");
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$cookies = explode(";", $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    $parts = explode("=", $cookie);
    $name = trim($parts[0]);
    setcookie($name, "", time() -3600);
    setcookie($name, "", time() -3600, "/");
}
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
unset($_COOKIE);
```

However my `var_dump()` still contains the cookies!

Also, the page you're then redirected to, `login.php` contains the following code:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) {
    echo "Still set."
}
```

and low-and-behold, the page displays `Still set.`

Comment: Don't use "isset" when checking the cookie. Use: if(!empty($_COOKIE['login'])). Why? If you set it to "", it is still set. However, it is empty.

Comment: you will not see effect of removing a cookie until you refresh the page. The intention of removing cookie must travel to your browser, then remove it in your browser, and next header to your server will not contain that cookie. Only then your php will have not this cookie.

Comment: Do I need to refresh the page before I redirect? Or would the redirect be enough to remove the cookie?

Comment: header should be enough, if the cookie has the same path...

Comment: if you're using Chrome on Mac-OS X you may run into these issues [Session Cookies Not Cleared When Chrome Processes Closed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove all cookies from any available Cookie tools or your browser's developer tool.

Always write COOKIES as '/' with respect to entire domain of site. Path play an important role when we set/unset cookies. Use 
`setcookie($cookie_name, "$cookie_value", time() +3600, "/")` to set and `setcookie($cookie_name, "$cookie_value", time() -360000, "/")` to unset COOKIES.

Further read here for about COOKIES path: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp

Hope it helps you